# cmd.exe Appears to Hang on Launch in Scheduled Task

Tags: command-line, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I have an application I've built to replicate data across a couple of different databases. This application is currently running via a Scheduled Task on a Windows Server 2019 VM at 5:00 A.M. daily. The task is set to run with elevated privileges under an administrative user account, whether or not the user is logged in. Most days it appears to run just fine and I receive my notification e-mail of a successful (or potentially failed) completion as expected.

However, *some* mornings I find that I *did not* get the notification message. I look in the **Task Scheduler** history for the task that runs my application and I see that it states that the execution was terminated because it reached my "timeout" of 8 hours (*when successful, the task usually takes less than 10 minutes to complete*).

In my efforts to isolate and troubleshoot the problem, I've added a fair deal of verbose logging to the application. At the point where it appears to be failing, the application is starting a new `cmd.exe` process to run `pg_dump`. But here's where things start to get a little strange.

A successful completion of the task produces a log that looks something like this (*redacted*):

```
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.3165]
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] C:\Windows\system32>CLS
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] C:\Windows\system32>SET PGPASSWORD=<DBPASSWORD>
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] C:\Windows\system32>PUSHD "\\<PGSQLHOST>\C$\PGSQL\bin"
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] Y:\PGSQL\bin>SET BinPath=%cd%
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:11] [  INFO ] Y:\PGSQL\bin>%BinPath%\pg_dump.exe -h <PGSQLHOST> -U <DBUSER> -p 5432 -E UTF8 -v -f "\\<ARCHIVESERVER>\Archives\SchemaName.pgdmp" --schema \"SchemaName\" <DBNAME>
[05:01:17] [  WARN ] pg_dump: <A BUNCH OF LINES DETAILING WHAT pg_dump IS DOING>
[05:01:17] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:17] [  INFO ] Y:\PGSQL\bin>POPD
[05:01:17] [  INFO ] 
[05:01:17] [  INFO ] C:\Windows\System32>EXIT
```

But, when I check the log on a day where the process timed out, this is ***literally*** all I see (***NOT** redacted*):

```
[05:01:08] [  INFO ] Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.3165]
[05:01:08] [  INFO ] (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[05:01:08] [  INFO ]
```

Not even the first `CLS` command is being executed (*yes, I realize it's somewhat "superfluous" since it's being run from a scheduled task*). This seems to me to indicate that `cmd.exe` is "hanging" for some reason as soon as it's being called. I tried looking in the **Event Viewer** for the failed day, but there are no events that appear to be connected with the application and very few events at all that appear at the time the log indicates - none in the **Application** event log, a couple of successful audit messages in the **Security** event logs, and nothing else that I can see related to the executable or the scheduled task in that time frame.

I've not ever encountered this issue when running the executable manually (*independent of the **Task Scheduler***), but it will intermittently occur whether the scheduled task is launched automatically on its regular schedule or if I start it myself from within the **Task Scheduler**.

Even so, as I said above, it doesn't *always* happen. If it did, this would obviously be a lot easier to diagnose. I've tried adjusting the schedule timing to ensure no other tasks or processes *should* be interfering with it but, as far as I can tell, that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there somewhere else that I'm overlooking where I might find evidence of what's actually happening here?

**NOTE:** Because this *is* an in-house application I've developed myself, I considered posting this question on StackOverflow, but decided this site was more appropriate since the code apparently "works". However, if providing some of the application's code would aid in diagnostics, please let me know. For reference, the application is a command line application written in VB.NET.

Comment: This might rather relate to the script that's calling CMD.

Comment: @harrymc - Yeah, I realize that's a distinct possibility, but the fact that it works most of the time is, I think, what's throwing me the most. I have quite a bit of error handling in the application that *should* catch exceptions during execution (even "unhandled" ones) and I've yet to find any specific evidence or indications of where the actual problem itself is occurring. I may post a related question on SO to try and come at the problem from a different angle.

Comment: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2309981-inconsistent-behavior-from-simple-one-line-script-run-from-task-scheduler I have found the root cause of the inconsistency.  It is all about priority.  Task Scheduler runs it's tasks with a below normal priority of 7.  If the server is already under memory pressure when the task starts, the process will struggle to get the resources to execute.  I did not see a way to alter the priority from the GUI.  But I was able to export the task definition, edit the XML, delete the old task, then import the task.

Comment: https://aavtech.site/2018/01/windows-task-scheduler-changing-task-priority/

Comment: @Gantendo - Thank you for the reference. I'll try adjusting the priority (setting it to `3`) and see if that seems to make a difference.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat This explains why the problem happens sporadically, and why it does not happen when you start the program manually. So I am pretty sure this will fix it. If it does, please donate at least 7 cents of your local currency to a charity of your choice. Thank you.

Comment: Well, I might have to wait a week or so to determine if the priority change is actually having any effect, but it seems promising so far. I'll try to remember to come back and update the question, but please feel free to post it as an actual answer so that I can accept it if it does, in fact, resolve the issue.

Comment: is Y:\ a mapped network drive? If so, don't use Y:\ in the script, use the full unc path. (\\server\path). When a task runs, often it is in the context of system and does not have a Y: map on the system where it is running. This is a big culprit in a lot of automated windows tasking failures.

Comment: @Narzard - Thank you, but `Y:` is "mapped" on-the-fly as a result of the **[`PUSHD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd)** command b/c the command line can't use a UNC path as the "current directory". It's then "unmapped" at the end of the script with the **[`POPD`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/popd)** command. This way, I'm reasonably certain that whatever drive letter the `PUSHD` command assigns will be available in the context of the current session.

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat gotcha - I was answering too fast and glanced over that pushd

Comment: @G_Hosa_Phat OK, I turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The default priority of processes run using Task Scheduler in Windows is below-normal (7).

```
Task Priority   Priority Category
0       Real-time
1       High
2-3     Above Normal
4-6     Normal
7-8     Below Normal
9-10    Idle
```

If the server is already under memory pressure when the task starts, the process will struggle to get the resources to execute.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the task-priority from within the Task Scheduler GUI. Here is one of the relatively easier ways to change the task-priority. Right click on the task in Task Scheduler and export the task as an XML file.

[image]

Modify the element named priority in the XML file to the task-priority you want. For example, you could set priority to 5 for setting normal priority.

[image]

Delete the original task from Task Scheduler

Choose the import task option either from right-click menu or actions sidebar to import the task back.

[image]

Credits: https://aavtech.site/2018/01/windows-task-scheduler-changing-task-priority/ and https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2309981-inconsistent-behavior-from-simple-one-line-script-run-from-task-scheduler

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for all the explanation and references. It certainly sounds like this may resolve the issue. I've changed the priority of the task to **`3`**. I'm going to let it run like that for a few days to see if the problem persists. If all seems well, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that did not seem to resolve the issue: I didn't get my notification e-mail this morning and, when I went to check the logs, I see the same results as in my OP. Checking the server on which the scheduled task is set up shows the task to still be running. Apparently, there's *still* something interfering with it. I can try setting the priority to **`1`**, but I have a feeling I'm still "missing" something at this point.