# Is Task Scheduler's StartComponentCleanup the exact same utility/process as dism.exe's StartComponentCleanup?

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, dism, winsxs

I have a computer that I can only access remotely, and running a scheduled Microsoft/Windows/Servicing/StartComponentCleanup with Task Scheduler seems to timeout after several hours. However, when I manually run dism.exe's StartComponentCleanup in the background, it always seems to complete after an hour or so.

I would like to know if the problem lies with Task Scheduler, or if different utilities (with different chances of success) are being used.

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://superuser.com/questions/1737129/cmd-exe-appears-to-hang-on-launch-in-scheduled-task#comment2690026_1737129

Comment: @Gantendo Did not know you could change the priority by jimmying with an XML file. Interesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 1 hour timeout when the cleanup is initiated by the scheduled task, but there is no such timeout when ran manually, that's what the [documentation says](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-10).

> The StartComponentCleanup task automatically cleans up components when the system isn't in use. When run automatically, the task will wait at least 30 days after an updated component has been installed before uninstalling the previous versions of the component.
>
> If you choose to run this task, the task will have a 1 hour timeout and may not completely clean up all files.

> Using the /StartComponentCleanup parameter of Dism.exe on a running version of Windows 10 or later gives you similar results to running the StartComponentCleanup task in Task Scheduler, except previous versions of updated components will be immediately deleted (without a 30 day grace period) and you will not have a 1-hour timeout limitation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I managed to miss that very last line when I read the docs.